# How to insert "fractions" in MS Word quickly

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, shortcuts

I need to insert fractions(other than 1/2 etc...)
I know it can be done by Equation-->Fractions but it is too time consuming and I need to do it quickly and repetitively.
Any other way around this or perhaps mapping a shortcut key?
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the shortcut keys: Alt+= and then type the equation out, like 3/4. Then, press space and Word will automatically typeset it correctly.